# Creating discount system for specific period

Tags: php, codeigniter, e-commerce

I'm using CodeIgniter, I want to offer discount for limited period of time. I don't know how to code it, would sessions be okay? But what if I want it only for first 15 mins, how can I manage that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

You might have to change your logic slightly to make this work.

```
<?php
    function discount_period($field,$time)
    {
        $t = time();
        $t0 = $_SESSION[$field];
        $diff = $t - $t0;
        if ($time > 1500 || !isset($t0))
        {          
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION[$field] = time();
        }
    }

    /* Inside your header */

    if(discount_period("user_time",1500))
    {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        location("some-other-page.php");          
        exit;
    }    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you gonna do it but you can use this snippet of code as a reference.

```
<?php

$userLoggedInDate = new DateTime('now'); //The time user logged in. You can store it in the session variable the first time the user had logged in.

$promoDate = 'April 26, 2014';
$date = new DateTime($promoDate); //promo start date
$date2 = new DateTime($promoDate.'+15 min'); //add 15 mins to the date

var_dump($userLoggedInDate>$date2); //is logged in date greater than the promo end time? 
var_dump($userLoggedInDate<$date2); //is logged in date less than the promo end time?
```